# Custom css added to page.xml in Magento is not loading

Tags: css, xml, magento

I have a custom css.I have placed it in the theme that we are using - skin\frontend\my-theme\default\css\custom.css

Now I have called this file in page.xml - app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/layout/page.xml

Syntax:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default translate="label" module="page">
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
</block>
</default>
</layout>
```

When I check view source, I don't see my custom.css.

Can you tell me what is wrong and how I get get to work custom.css?

Comment: did you clear cache after adding css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>

    <default>

        <reference name="head">

            <!-- /skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/css/custom.css -->
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name><params/></action>

        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

Or :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>

    <default>

        <reference name="head">

            <!-- /skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/css/custom.css -->
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>

        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

When you want to insert something in an existing bloc, you have to use "reference" tag. Put the block name in the "name" attribute.
You can now add everything you want to your existing block (like childs, css, templates...).